# call a function within a script without 'source'

Tags: bash

I thought it would be easy to find an answer to this question, but I can find nothing on the web:

I have a function declared in .bashrc. I want to call that function from within a script.  If I type:

```
$> source scriptname
```

the function is found. If I try:

```
$> scriptname
```

the function is not found.

At this point I can't see any reason why bash wants to make this difficult. Is there some way to make the 'source'ing automatic?

Comment: Is there are reason for not using `source`?  It exists as a means of importing the contents of one script into another.

Comment: Ksh93+ has the FPATH variable. Maybe bash 4 has added that. See http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html for info on FPATH. Good luck.

Comment: accept answers on your questions so people know they are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute with `./scriptname`, but that will create a new process, so all the defined/exported variables, aliases and everything will be lost after the script is finished.

Keep using `source scriptname` or `. scriptname`.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use '.' or 'source' is just convinience, I'm creating a bunch of 'wrappers' around commonly used commands, just to, in effect, create very quick, simplified versions of them with the defaults I like, and with a very simple and consistent argument list. Since speed is the main point of this, anything that adds to the typing is to be avoided if possible.

Comment: So, use the short form -- the dot followed by whitespace followed by your filename!

Comment: I don't understand your "speed" "argument".. are you saying that because you have to type `source` it's going to be slower? that's not the case.

Comment: Well, if I hafta, I hafta. But I don't know why bash has to be so difficult about things. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: I don't know *any* language where you can import a source just by typing its name. I don't see difficulty here, and if you do you got the wrong mindset. ah, and pls accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call it directly by the name, you can write a small shell script for it and place it in some directory in the `PATH`.

e.g. File scriptname:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting `basename $0`"
# Other processing
echo "Completed `basename $0`"
```

Place it in some directory like `/usr/bin`, then you'll need to call `scriptname` from the command line without '.' or 'source'.

Hope this answers your question.